# algorithm- for counting pairwise mutual occurrences

Tags: algorithm

I have a list of lists. 
    L1= [[...][...][.....].....]
If I take all the elements after flattening the list and extract unique values from it then i get a list L2.
I have another list L3 which is some subset of L2.

I want to find the pair-wise mutual occurrences of the elements of L3 in L1. Relation is non-directed. i.e. a,b is same as b,a

eg-
    L1= [[a b c d][a b d g f][c d g][d g]....]
    L2=[a b c d g f]
    say L3 = [c d g]

I want to find pair wise mutual occurrences of L3 in L1. i.e these values. 
    c,d:2
    d,g:3
    c,g:1

I'm getting O(n*n*m*p); where- p- no. of lists in L1, m - avg. no. of elements in each list of L1. n - no. of elements in L3.

Can I get an improved complexity?

Code for above in python is:

Here sig_tags is L3 and tags is L1.

```
x=[]
    for i in range(len(sig_tags)):
        for j in range(i+1,len(sig_tags)):
            count=0
            for k in tags:
                if (sig_tags[i] in k) and (sig_tags[j] in k):
                    count+=1
            if count>param:        
                x.append([sig_tags[i],sig_tags[j],count])
    return x
```

Comment: So if the L3 has 10 letters in it, should it print out all the pairs out of the 10 letters? 45 pairs?

Comment: yes, it should have all the 45 pairs.

Comment: I don't think you can improve complexity then. There will be n*(n-1)/2 pairs which is O(n²) and you'll have to at least read all the elements in L1 so it's O(n²m) which is what you have. Maybe if you shared your algorithm we could take a look and offer improvements.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

Give each element an id, then convert the list L1 into a list of bit vectors, where a bit is true if that list constains the corresponding letter. This is O(m*p), or O(M*p*log|Alphabet|) depending how you implement it.

Now to check if a pair belongs to a list you need to check if cerain 2 bits are true which is O(1). So all the checks are going to be O(n^2*p).

Overall the complexity is O(n^2*p + m*p).

You can skip assiging ids if you use a hash function. Be careful, sometimes the hash function computation is expensive.

Comment: I think this approach would become expensive in space terms. Just to give an idea- number of lists in L1 are huge, its In lakhs(keeps increasing every week.). And size of each list in it is very very less than L1 somewhere around 10. Number of entries in L3 is around 1000.

Comment: You can filp the order so that you take a list from L1, convert that to a vector of bits (bools) then check all the combinations from L3. The complexity stays the same, but you only need to store O(alphabet ) extra memory.